# issue with updating existing pdf file

Tags: php, yii, fpdf

I am having a pdf form of 10-11 pages. I need to fill it using the php. Also I need to add one signature of the user which is  a images of png type. For filling a form, I found the solution here : `https://github.com/yiiext/pdf`. It fills up form correctly. But later I need to add the signature image to generated pdf file. For that I used the fpdf and fpdi libraries. It includes the the signature to appropriate place, but the problem is that, all the filled pdf form values gets clean.

```
        require_once('protected/extensions/fpdf/fpdf.php');
        require_once('protected/extensions/fpdf/fpdi.php');


        $pdf =& new FPDI();
        $pdf->AddPage(); 
        $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('FilledPdfForm.pdf');
        $tppl = $pdf->importPage(3);


        $pdf->useTemplate($tppl, -10, 20, 210);


        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
        $pdf->SetXY(90, 160);

        $pdf->Image('finpay.png',45,220,15,10) ; 
        $pdf->Output('modified_pdf.pdf', 'F');
```

Does anybody knows the solution? 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [cannot edit a PDF document with FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-202) but you will import existing pages of an existing document into a structure that you can re-use with FPDF.

Form fields (or any other page annotation) are not part of a pages content stream and will get lost when importing a page with FPDI.

If you need to fill in an existing PDF form while filling another field with an image you may give [this](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/demos/fill-form-field-with-image/) a try (it's not free but a solution).